# JupyterLab - keyboard shortcut for moving a tab right/left

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, jupyter-lab

In JupyterLab is there any command for moving a tab right/left? I am changing my mappings and want to add that to a key.

Comment: I don't think so. Do you mean moving the tab in tabbar right/left, or moving the tab contents to split panel rigth/left? The latter has an issue open: https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/11373, for the former please open a feature request (and ideally a pull request if you are able and would like to).

Comment: Moving the tab (no splitting). Unfortunately I do not have the knowledge to fix it myself

Comment: That's fine! Opening an issue clearly describing what you would like to achieve is a first step, and then someone else can pick up (or a maintainer can provide step by step instructions if this is an easy one).